# How to put Fraction number in front of unit in SASS

Tags: css, sass, libsass

I have the following SASS code:

```
margin: #{-5/16}rem
```

I get with this code:

```
margin: -5/16rem
```

I want this output:

```
margin: -0.3125rem
```

I also tried this:

```
margin: (-5/16)rem
```

but this results in:

```
margin: -0.3125 rem <- notice the space between number and unit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried combining both your notations and it seems to properly work (*Sass v3.4.25*):

```
margin: #{(-5/16)}rem; /* margin: -0.3125rem; */
```

> [Sassmeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/05f85bc11cc395a5fde025523431ef50)

Answer (score 0):

Sass can directly do math with units, so the correct syntax to get your desired result is:

```
margin: (-5rem/16)
```